# Error running GAE tutorial code - Guestbook

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to follow Google's python tutorial for the guestbook, and it's unclear what code to add or change where as I go through it, so now I'm getting an internal server error when I run the finished code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google App Engine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google App Engine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google App Engine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google App Engine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google App Engine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google App Engine\lib\webapp2-2.5.2\webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Minhhanh\Desktop\guestbook\guestbook.py", line 34, in get
    DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME)
NameError: global name 'DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME' is not defined
```

I'm not sure what to do with the 'DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME', and if I change it to some other string, I get a different error about the guestbook key. My code is currently spread across 4 files: app.yaml, index.yaml, index.html, guestbook.py. Not sure what to do from here.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states you don't have the variable named DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME defined anywhere.

Add :

```
DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME = 'Your default book name'
```

before using that variable.

Comment: Why doesn't the tutorial include this variable definition? I'm not even sure where to put it, given that everything in python is classes and it could be private.
 Now I get a new error: line 38, in get
    ancestor=guestbook_key(guestbook_name)).order(-Greeting.date)
NameError: global name 'guestbook_key' is not defined

Comment: can you provide the link to the tutorial you are talking about? May be you are looking at snippet of the tutorial not the complete one.

Comment: It's a multi-page tutorial, starting here: [link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/authenticating-users)
Even from the first page, they introduce DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME without a definition. Then later, guestbook_key. I don't know how to define that method myself yet. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Yes. you are looking at the incomplete tutorial. You can access the complete tutorial by going to the github link in the same page. or going to https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-python/blob/master/guestbook.py

Comment: Wow, thanks, that's much more than what's in the tutorial. It said to 'clone the repository with git' at the beginning, but I didn't know what that meant. I think Google should clarify the steps for this.